# Add internal CI badge to Github README changes the image URL

Tags: github

I'm trying to add a build status badge of TeamCity to a private Github README.
The problem is the CI server is only accessible to an internal network and when viewing the Github project page I see that the image URL I've put in the markdown is not the URL of the image, instead, Github changes the image URL to Github own URL.

Is there a way to ask Github to not change the URL so that the browser running in the internal network will be the one fetching the badge instead of Github's server?

Comment: you might want to contact github to see if this is even possible. The raw inputs on the readme don't change, but the displayed readme does, seems like that's the way they want it.

Comment: of course the raw readme didn't got changed :) the viewer of github changes it. I hope by writing here github might contact me :)

Comment: GitHub will not contact you here. The gods were banished from these forsaken lands. You will have to contact them directly.